# Is there any other way to display UIView into ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal, arkit

Here below my code and camera image to load 2d `UIView` into `sceneView`. I already tried to load into material content but getting node many times blank.

[image]

```
let annotationNode = SCNNode()      
let planeGeoMetry:SCNPlane = SCNPlane()
planeGeoMetry.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .fill

planeGeoMetry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = view
annotationNode.name = name
annotationNode.geometry = planeGeoMetry   
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(annotationNode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apples docs on [`SCNMaterialProperty.contents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents):

> SceneKit cannot use a layer that is already being displayed elsewhere (for example, the backing layer of a 
>   UIView
>    object)

Personally the easiest way of displaying information on a plane is using a [SpriteKit Scene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene).